# How to know the figure reference of a chart done in python with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to iterate over several figures done with matplotlib. 
Only one of the figures is done "directly" with Pandas Visualization. 
In the code below will show an example with just 2 figures, one done with matplotlib API and one done directly with Pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=10)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))  
df['B'] = np.random.randint(-1,2,size=10)
df['i'] = range(1,11)

# first figure done with matplotlib API
fig1    = plt.figure()
ax1     = plt.subplot2grid((5,1),(0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax1     = ax1.plot(df.A)


# second figure done with pandas
fig2    = plt.figure()
ax_bar  = df[df.columns].tail(1).plot(kind='bar',legend=True)
ax_bar.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

If you run this code you are going to actually get 3 figures.

First one is fig1 wich is correct, second one is fig2 that is blank and third figure is the ax_bar chart.

`type(ax_bar)` gives you `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`

So my question is, how can I know or define the name of the figure to  be associated with ax_bar plot?

Because the goal is that in the end one could iterate over all the figures, so for example:

`figures = [fig1,fig2]`, so `figures` is a list and one can iterate over it (to be able to complete another process that needs to be done), but this currently can't be done as fig2 is blank and I don't know how to call the figure done with pandas.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can do: `plt.gcf()` to get the current figure...

Comment: going to edit  it  to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`plt.gcf()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gcf) to get the current figure after plotting with Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=10)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))  
df['B'] = np.random.randint(-1,2,size=10)
df['i'] = range(1,11)

# first figure done with matplotlib API
fig1    = plt.figure()
ax1     = plt.subplot2grid((5,1),(0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax1     = ax1.plot(df.A)

# second figure done with pandas
ax_bar  = df[df.columns].tail(1).plot(kind='bar',legend=True)
ax_bar.xaxis.set_visible(False)
fig2 = plt.gcf() # <- use this

figures = [fig1,fig2]
for fig in figures:
    print(fig)
```

Results in:

```
>>> for fig in figures:
...     print(fig)
...
Figure(640x440)
Figure(640x440)
```

Comment: I got comment and answer

Comment: Thanks, @piRSquared! Much appreciated :-)

Comment: Answer too now!